# Create view that takes data from 2 tables and also has own rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i have two table

```
student(name,lastname,year,departament,id)
course(cname,cyear,cdepartament)
```

So i want to take from student name,lastname,year(exmp:if he is on the first year of school then year = first) AND from course cname,cyear
My big problem is: TO CREATE NEW view THAT HAS name,lastname,year,cname,cyear AND grade!!!
Is that possible to put new row on view?

Comment: Please let us know what the relationship between the data in the two tables is.  Please also show us what queries you have set up, what you've tried and we'll help you!

Comment: A view is just a stored query. So once you have a query that does what you want them you can convert it into a view, They are useful because you can use them in other queries exactly as you would a table.

Comment: Thank you!!!my question is : IS possible to create view that has an own row?AND the answer i guess is not....So thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by 'own row' - please give an actual example of what you want to see and where it comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view always has to pull from a table.  You can create a view with computed columns or with static data, but you cannot create a view that has it columns of it's own like a table does.